# Bind CommandParameter to property of owning object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am building a dynamic context menu. To make that happen I have come up with a custom viewmodel that represents my contextmenu, defined like this:

```
public class ContextMenuVM {
  public object ContextItem { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<ICommand> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

The property `Items` holds the effective commands to show in the contextmenu and the property `ContextItem` holds the context-item that these commands are to be executed on.

Further, I have a singleton class which holds all my various commands and their implementation. So in the end there will be a method that will be called `UpdateContextMenu` on the viewmodel that owns the contextmenu that does something like this:

```
ContextMenu.Items.Clear();
ContextMenu.Items.Add(SingletonClass.Instance.CommandA);
if (condition)
  ContextMenu.Items.Add(SingletonClass.Instance.CommandB);
```

The ContextMenu iteself in XAML is defined like this:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContextMenu.Items}">
  <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl>
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding}" CommandParameter="what-goes-here?" />
      </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

What I fail to achieve is getting the `CommandParameter` binding to work. How am I supposed to bind to the `ContextItem` property of the `ContextMenuVM` instance?

Answer (score 0):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows what you're doing, it's impossible to know for sure. But based on the information you've provided so far, it seems like you are looking for the `RelativeSource` binding source. E.g.:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContextMenu.Items}">
  <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl>
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ContextMenu.ContextItem
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
      </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

I had to make a guess as to the binding path, based on your `ItemsSource` binding, because your original code example isn't complete. The basic idea is to bind to a path that is relative to the specified source, so I've assumed that the `ContextMenu` refers to a property that returns the `ContextMenuVM` object you are using.

If this doesn't address your question, please improve it by providing a good MCVE.